# Enviar DataTable a otro controlador ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web ASP.NET MVC C#, y estoy tratando de enviar un DataTable que se crea en un controlador, la cual ocupo enviar a otro controlador para poder utilizarla, lo cual no logró realizar.

¿Existe manera? 
¿Como se podría resolver?

Aquí se carga el DataTable en el controlador.

```
DataRow row = dtTokens.NewRow();
                    row["Token"] = sNuevacadena;
                    row["Descuento"] = token_descuentos.porcentajeDescuento;
                    row["Vendedor"] = NombreVendedor;
                    row["Carrera"] = NombreCarrera;
                    row["Distancia"] = NombreDistancia;

                    dtTokens.Rows.Add(row);


                TempData["listaTokens"] = dtTokens;

                return RedirectToAction("ListaTokensNuevos", "Reportes");
```

Comment: Como estas intentando recuperar la tabla de la variable temporal en el otro controllador?

Comment: De esta manera var pruebaTabla = TempData["listaTokens"];

Comment: Hola, indica el código de la Acción `ListaTokensNuevos`

Comment: Otra manera de hacerlo es que en tu Acction ListaTokensNuevos aceptes un modelo: y entonces le pases el valor de la tabla como parametro:return RedirectToAction("ListaTokensNuevos", "Reportes", TokenNuevosViewModel.TablaTokens);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás redirigiendo a la Acción `ListaTokensNuevos()`, dentro de esta Acción recupera el `DataTable` de la siguiente manera:

```
DataTable dtTokens = TempData["listaTokens"] as DataTable;
```

o también

```
var dtTokens = (DataTable)TempData["listaTokens"];
```

Comment: Listo muchas gracias ¡Pura vida!